# How to identify base image layers in docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I need to identify which docker image layers belong to base image.
For example, "mysql" image consists of base image "debian" and also several layers.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker history mysql
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
d72169616e20        5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["mysqld"]               0B
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 3306 33060            0B
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry…   0B
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entryp…   34B
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:1667e4be6bef3129…   6.53kB
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:478f098f3681084f7…   1.22kB
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/var/lib/mysql]      0B
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c {   echo mysql-community-server m…   328MB
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/a…   56B
<missing>           5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.16-…   0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0          0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex;  key='A4A9406876FCBD3C45…   27.8kB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   44.8MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d    0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -x  && apt-get update && apt-…   4.44MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.7         0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   10.2MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -…   329kB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:4fc310c0cb879c876…   55.3MB
```

Imagine pulling image named "X" that has base image "mysql" and other layers, How can I know which layers are for "mysql" and the other layers are for image "X"

"docker history X" command show me all layers but doesn't refer each layer if its to base image or not.

Is any idea or any tool that can help me?

Comment: Did you only want to determine the base-layer knowing that `mysql` is a child of `debian` or is your use-case to find the parent?

Comment: "mysql" is an example, and I want to know that identify which layers in image "X" are taken from "mysql" and which are new/added

Comment: I don't reale get your point or can help you. But may it is useful for you to write an own image from a base image und inspect this with `docker history IMAGE_ID`. Then you know which steps you had run in your `Dockerfile` and the left col has more as `<missing>`. This is may possible way to learn more about this topic.

Comment: Not good enough, docker history will show us <missing> value for all layers if we pull the image for example from dockerhub.